# I'm at a loss at finding the segfault in my program

Tags: c

So I've been spending hours trying to find the source of this segmentation fault 11 error, and I was hoping if you guys can help me out.

So the purpose of the program is to find redirection in a input string, and return a redirCode struct that gives direction of redirection, the fileName, and the argsWithoutFile.

Example input:

```
"ls -a > test.txt"
```

returns a redir code with:

```
argsWithoutFile = "ls -a"
fileName = "test.txt"
code = 2                     //stdout
```

I'm pretty sure the seg fault is coming from trying to do the substrings. The for loop seems fine, because when I comment out the substring stuff at the end it doesn't give a segfault. Everything seems fine to me except for the substring. Basically for substring I want it to be like this:

```
char *input = "ls -a > test.txt'
char *desiredSubString = "ls -a "
```

---

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER      1024
struct redirCode findRedirects(char *input);
struct redirCode {
    /* For code:
     * 0 = none
     * 1 = stdin
     * 2 = stdout
     */
    int code;
    char *argsWithoutFile;
    char *fileName;
};

int main(){
    const char *delims = "<>";
    struct redirCode temp;
    char line[BUFFER];

    printf("Input: ");
    fgets(line, 1024, stdin);
    temp = findRedirects(line);

    printf("temp:\n");
    printf("temp.code = %d\n", temp.code);
    printf("temp.fileName = %s\n", temp.fileName);
    printf("temp.argsWithoutFile = %s\n", temp.argsWithoutFile);

}

/* Looks for '>', '<' in a string.
 * Will destroy string *input
 * Returns a redirCode struct with:
 * 1. fileName - the name of file that
 * wants to be redirected/stdin
 * 2. code - the direction of redirect
 * 3. args - the arguments w/o filename
 * */
struct redirCode findRedirects(char *input)
{
    const char *delims = "<>";
    struct redirCode redirToReturn;

    //Do an initial search for the delimeters
    //before strtok destroys it. O(n) time.
    int redirectOperatorReached = 0;
    int count = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; input[i] != 0; i++){
        if (input[i] == '<'){
            redirToReturn.code = 1;
            redirectOperatorReached = 1;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '>'){
            redirToReturn.code = 2;
            redirectOperatorReached = 1;
        }
        else {
            redirToReturn.code = 0;
        }
        if (redirectOperatorReached != 1){
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("sizeof(input) = %lu\n", sizeof(input));
    printf("count = %d\n", count);
    strncpy(redirToReturn.argsWithoutFile, input, count);
    printf("input = %s\n", input);
    redirToReturn.argsWithoutFile[count] = '\0';
    printf("argsW/oFile = %s\n", redirToReturn.argsWithoutFile);

    return redirToReturn;
}
```

And here are some terminal logs

```
MacBook-Air:practice keithy$ cc strtokOnlyOnce.c
MacBook-Air:practice keithy$ ./a.out
Input: hi
sizeof(input) = 8
count = 3
Segmentation fault: 11
MacBook-Air:practice keithy$ cc strtokOnlyOnce.c
MacBook-Air:practice keithy$ ./a.out
Input: ls -a > test.txt
sizeof(input) = 8
count = 6
Segmentation fault: 11
MacBook-Air:practice keithy$
```

---

EDIT: I got it to work! All I had to do was malloc the strings in redirCode. Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFFER      1024
struct redirCode findRedirects(char *input);
struct redirCode {
    /* For code:
     * 0 = none
     * 1 = stdin
     * 2 = stdout
     */
    int code;
    char *argsWithoutFile;
    char *fileName;
};

int main(){
    const char *delims = "<>";
    struct redirCode temp;
    char line[BUFFER];

    printf("Input: ");
    fgets(line, 1024, stdin);
    temp = findRedirects(line);

    printf("temp.code = %d\n", temp.code);
    printf("temp.fileName = %s\n", temp.fileName);
    printf("temp.argsWithoutFile = %s\n", temp.argsWithoutFile);

}

/* Looks for '>', '<' in a string.
 * Will destroy string *input
 * Returns a redirCode struct with:
 * 1. fileName - the name of file that
 * wants to be redirected/stdin
 * 2. code - the direction of redirect
 * 3. args - the arguments w/o filename
 * */
struct redirCode findRedirects(char *input)
{
    const char *delims = "<>";
    struct redirCode *redirToReturn = malloc(sizeof(struct redirCode));

    //Do an initial search for the delimeters
    //before strtok destroys it. O(n) time.
    int redirectOperatorReached = 0;
    int count = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; input[i] != 0; i++){
        if (input[i] == '<'){
            redirToReturn->code = 1;
            redirectOperatorReached = 1;
            input[i] = ' ';
        }
        else if (input[i] == '>'){
            redirToReturn->code = 2;
            redirectOperatorReached = 1;
            input[i] = ' ';
        }
        if (redirectOperatorReached != 1){
            count++;
        }
    }
    int lengthOfInput = strlen(input);

    int sizeOfMalloc = (lengthOfInput+1)*sizeof(char);
    redirToReturn->argsWithoutFile = (char *) malloc(sizeOfMalloc);
    redirToReturn->fileName = (char *) malloc(sizeOfMalloc);

    strncpy(redirToReturn->argsWithoutFile, input, count);
    redirToReturn->argsWithoutFile[count] = '\0';

    strncpy(redirToReturn->fileName, input + count, lengthOfInput - count);

    return *redirToReturn;
}

/*OUTPUT
 *./a.out
 *Input: ls -a > test.txt
 *temp.code = 2
 *temp.fileName =   test.txt
 *temp.argsWithoutFile = ls -a
*/
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? If you run a debugger with your program, then it will tell you exactly at what point in the program the segfault occurred.

Comment: argsWithoutFile is NULL (well, initialized with a random value). You first have to allocate a buffer then you can use it for strncpy .

Comment: You've done really well with your printf debugging, but you need to take it to the next step. The output identifies `strncpy(redirToReturn.argsWithoutFile, input, count);` as being the problem line. So, dig deeper there. Understanding what's wrong with this specific program isn't really the big issue. This is your chance to learn some debugging skills that will serve you for the rest of time.

Comment: Your `for` loop looks as though it will reset the code to zero as it scans the filename.  Also, commands can redirect both input and output, but that is probably a future enhancement.

Comment: note that `sizeof` is returning `8` regardless as it is giving you the size of the `char *` _pointer_ and not the _data_ that it is pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  struct redirCode {
        /* For code:
         * 0 = none
         * 1 = stdin
         * 2 = stdout
         */
        int code;
        char *argsWithoutFile;
        char *fileName;
    };
```

You need to allocate memory for structure member named `char *argsWithoutFile;` and `char *fileName;` before using it.

You can do like this

```
struct redirCode *redirToReturn = malloc(sizeof(struct redirCode ));
redirToReturn->argsWithoutFile = malloc(1024);
redirToReturn->fileName = malloc(1024);
```

Answer (score 1):

1->
You need to allocate memory to `argsWithoutFile`
 using `new`/`malloc` before doing `strncpy`
2->
filename is not initialized and you are printing it in printf. this is Undefined behavior.